# Plugin de sublimetext 3 para mostrar errores

Tags: plugin, sublimetext3

¿Qué plugin en sublimetext3 me dice que hay un error en la sintaxis de php html y css?

Si es posible que diga cual es el error.

Instalé sublimelinter pero no sé si lo instalé mal o tenía que instalar otro paquete no me sirvió.

Comment: ¿agregaste los linter plugin respectivos para cada lenguaje?

Comment: para que quieres un plugin en php?

Comment: no es necesario hacer eso, el navegador te dice los errores

Comment: @Shaz Debo agregar los plugins necesarios? cuales son ? De antemano gracias

Comment: @CriticalGhost bueno php no me es tab importante pero si css y html. para nosotros que sabemos muy poco seria muy util, ya que el dreamweaver es muy pesado. Me gustaría que el sublime me dijera y no recurrir al navegador por cada linea que escribo

Comment: bueno, normalmente los errores de html y css son errores tipo visual, es decir, que puedes ver como afecta el diseño cuando haces una modificacion

Comment: @Daniel bueno, yo uso sublimetext

Comment: es mi editor de texto favorito

Comment: Pero que plugin instalo en sublime para que me diga en la linea 20 y columna 15 hay X error me insteresa css y html. gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Bueno dame unos minutos y te publico la respuesta

Comment: @Daniel por favor no uses Dreamweaver, quedo pendiente de la respuesta de Critical Ghost.

Comment: Denme unos 10 minutos, mientras realizo una cosa que debo entregar

Comment: La respues es algo extensa asi que te hare un resumen y te dejare los links de las paginas para resolver tus demas dudas

Comment: @CriticalGhost Agradezco tu respuesta Después de instalar Package Control: instalo install package luego el  sublimelinter hasta ahí llego debo instalar otro plugin adicional?

Comment: para que no te pierdas siguelo paso a paso, si tu sublime no tiene package control, si quieres activalo, hay te deje el link para activarlo, y si quieres puedes colocar mas plugins :3

Comment: sera mas facil la instalacion de los plugins

Comment: espera falto algo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenos Dias,

Hay varios plugins para ver los errores pero el mas complejo es el de `PHP`,

> PHP:

Bueno para los de `PHP` necesitas algunas cosas para el correcto funcionamiento del plugin el plugin se llama:

> PHP Code Sniffer.

Intalacion:

puede realizarse desde el administrador de paquetes de sublime en `menú > preferences > package-control` y posteriormente buscando la opción `“Install Package”.`

> Nota: si no tienes el package-control este link te ayudara para activarlo:
>   https://styde.net/gitgutter-para-sublime-text/

Una vez allí busca el paquete llamado `PHPCS`, presionas “enter” y esperas a que termine la instalación.
Configuración de `PHPCS`

Lo primero que debes hacer es descargar los siguientes ejecutables que son requeridos por el plugin para su funcionamiento

> PHP Code Sniffer:
>   http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected
>
> PHP Mess Detector: http://phpmd.org/
>
> PHP CS Fixer:  https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer
>
> PHP Code Beautifier: https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier

Una vez descargados los almacenas en cualquier lugar dentro de tu equipo local. PHPCS hace uso de estos binarios para comprobar la sintaxis del código de los archivos de tu proyecto y así poder marcar o resaltar los errores que puedan tener.

Ingresa desde Sublime Text a `menú > preferences > package settings > PHP Code Sniffer` y vas a ver 2 opciones `“Settings – Default”` y `“Settings -User”`. Abre primero el archivo `“Settings – Default”` copia el contenido del archivo y posteriormente abre el archivo `“Settings – User”`  y pega este contenido, guarda el archivo y de esta forma ya podrás cambiar la configuración por defecto y agregar tu configuración personalizada.

Los cambios mas importantes a realizar es agregar la dirección a cada ejecutable para que el plugin pueda funcionar. Toma en cuenta que en este caso estoy usando Windows por ello se utilizan los separadores “\”, en Ubuntu o MAC debes usar “/”.

```
"phpcs_php_prefix_path": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
"phpcs_executable_path": "C:\\xampp\\php\\phpcs.bat",
"php_cs_fixer_executable_path": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php-cs-fixer.phar",
"phpcbf_executable_path": "C:\\xampp\\php\\phpcbf.bat",
"phpcs_php_path": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
"phpmd_executable_path": "C:\\xampp\\php\\phpmd.phar",
```

La información que tengo que darte es demasiada, Porfavor este link te ayudara mas para instalar el pluglin de `PHP`: https://styde.net/instalar-php-code-sniffer-en-sublime-text/

El otro Plugin para HTML y CSS se llama `SublimeLinter`.

Para instalar este plugin necesitas tener el Package-control, de esta manera se te facilitara la manera de intalar los puglins que quieras.

Este link puede ayudarte: http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: Gracias por responder. esos pasos me sirven para html y css. (php no me es tan relevante ahora)?

Comment: bueno si quieres instalar el de php hazlo, pero el navegador te dice donde esta el error :3

Comment: Perdon. use mal los puntos y comas. Quise escribir: Me sirven para CSS y HTML? (que es el que me interesa actualmente)  (el php ahora no lo uso mucho)

Comment: llegando al final de la respuesta encuentras uno llamado SublimeLinter, hay te deje el link para que sigas los pasos ya que es mucha la informacion

Comment: Amigo gracias por tu ayuda. Instale SublimeLinter y hasta uno csslint pero nada, no me muestra los errores en el css.
Agradezco mucho tu ayuda, pero creo que seguire con el dreanweaver es pesado pero no complicado para novatos

Comment: que mal, pero no uses eso.... para eso usa Netbeans

Comment: Lo probare, pero sera que estay haciendo algo mal, Voy al Package control > install package > sublimelinter luego instalo sublimelinter-csslint. Que hago mal? debo configurar algo en el sublime???

Comment: si te das cuenta recuerda que te deje los links de descarga

Comment: de los otros plugins que necesitas para el funcionamiento del plugin de php

Comment: Aunque no este trabjando con php? es necesario instalarlos? en youtibe vi un tutorial y requisito instalar node ya abrir node.js. 
Solo html y css.
Este es el tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrPWpSShff4
pero bajo el node se abre la app store windows

Comment: mmmmm que mal amigo.... e estos momentos no estoy en mi pc.... pero hey! porque no usas atom!? es mucha mas facil descargar sus plugins

Comment: Corrige los errores que podria tener un novato en css? los muestra?

Comment: si, los corrigue @Daniel

Comment: y mucho mas... yo tengo de todo los detectores de errores... el de php es el que me falla

Comment: Lo bajara pero en mi casa porque donde estoy ahora el internet es lento y pesa alrededor de 100 megas contra los 10 del sublime jejej y el pc poca ram, motivo por el que no uso aca el dream...

Comment: ah ya, bueno ven a este chat porque ya hay mucho comentarios http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: Amigo ya lo solucione, La clave era instalar el node.js de node.org el problema es que en windows 10 me decía que no podia instalar app fiera de la tienda de windows 10 y al abrirlo me enviaba a la tienda de windows, basto con autorizar instalar app de terceros (fuera de la app store) y y correr este codigo en cms npm install -g csslint
Bueno gracias por toda tu colaboración

Comment: genial amigo !!! ya sabes aceptar la respuesta puede ser de muy buena ayuda emocional :3

Comment: @Daniel :3 me alegro muchop